# Can't delete record in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

Guys I'm trying to make a delete button to delete single record, I tried many ways but all fall, so if you can help me guys I'll appreciate it.

Laravel 4.2

here is the view code:

```
 {{ Form::open(['method' => 'delete', 'route' => [ 'orders.destroy', $orders->id ]]) }}
 {{ Form::hidden('id', $orders->id) }}
 {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
 {{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller code:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
$orders = orders::findOrFail($id);
$orders->delete();
return Redirect::route('orders.index');
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('orders/delete', [
'uses' => 'Admin\OrdersController@destroy',
'as'   => 'admin.orders'
]);
```

Error:

```
Undefined variable: orders (View:../app/views/orders/show.blade.php)
```

Comment: is it showing any errors?

Comment: @manian yes I got this error "Undefined variable: orders"

Comment: Is this error in your controller or in view or in your route? You mentioned 'orders.destroy' as route in your form but in your route you mentioned it as 'admin.orders'. I hope it should be  'orders.destroy' in your route too

Comment: Please post this error in your question so that someone will give you a solution if I am not able to. Also, it will be useful for other users for future references.

Comment: @manian thank you sir for your time, you are right I should include the error, now it is included in the question, and the error in the view blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it, so here is my solution:

Route:

```
Route::get('orders/delete/{id}',array
('as'=>'delete',
'uses'=>'Admin\OrdersController@delete'));
```

Add to controller uses

```
use DB;
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id)
   {
    DB::table('orders')->where('id',$id)->delete();
    return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Record has been deleted');
   }
```

Show Blade:

```
<a href="{{route('delete', array($order->id))}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```